# Turn one dataframe into several dfs and add them as CSVs to zip archive (without saving files locally)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, zip

I have a data frame which I read in from a locally saved CSV file.
I then want to loop over said file and create several CSV files based on a string in one column.

Lastly, I want to add all those files to a zip file, but without saving them locally. I just want one zip archive including all the different CSV files.

All my attempts using the **io** or **zipfile** modules only resulted in one zip file with one CSV file in it (pretty much with what I started with)

Any help would be much appreciated!
Here is my code so far, which works but saves all CSV files just to my hard drive.

```
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

df = pd.read_csv("myCSV.csv")
channelsList = df["Turn one column to list"].values.tolist()
channelsList = list(set(channelsList)) #delete duplicates from list

for channel in channelsList:
    newDf = df.loc[df['Something to match'] == channel]
    
    newDf.to_csv(f"{channel}.csv") # saves csv files to disk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.to_csv()` can write to any file-like object, and `ZipFile.writestr()` can accept a string (or bytes), so it is possible to avoid writing the CSV files to disk using `io.StringIO`.  See the example code below.

Note: If the `channel` is simply stored in a single column of your input data, then the more idiomatic (and more efficient) way to iterate over the partitions of your data is to use `groupby()`.

```
from io import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,3)), columns=[*'xyz'])
df['channel'] = np.random.randint(5, size=len(df))

with ZipFile('/tmp/output.zip', 'w') as zf:
    for channel, channel_df in df.groupby('channel'):
        s = StringIO()
        channel_df.to_csv(s, index=False, header=True)
        zf.writestr(f"{channel}.csv", s.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Worked for me, but instead of writing to CSV, I finally went with "channel_df.to_excel" and used BytesIO instead of StringIO.